# Поправить изгиб

Tags: svg, inkscape

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<svg width='100px'
   viewBox="0 0 10 10"
   inkscape:version="1.1.2 (b8e25be833, 2022-02-05)"
   sodipodi:docname="рисунок-6.svg"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg109101"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="256"
     inkscape:cx="4.859375"
     inkscape:cy="4.9003906"
     inkscape:window-width="2560"
     inkscape:window-height="1018"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     showguides="true"
     inkscape:guide-bbox="true"
     lock-margins="true"
     inkscape:lockguides="true"
     width="10px">
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="8.4561891,21.956885"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide104385" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="3.3824757,9.9401947"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide104395" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="1.6683301,5.0060584"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide107240" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="4.9939416,8.5415923"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide107242" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="4.0548154,8.5084466"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide107293" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="1.5026019,7.2378641"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide107295" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="5.4800775,1.5036701"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide107297" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="8.4963299,4.7519419"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide107388" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="4.6072426,6.0225244"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide107555" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="5.4027377,6.177204"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide107557" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="4.9939416,5.4038059"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide107559" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="5.4027377,4.5972623"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide107561" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <defs
     id="defs109096" />
  <ellipse
     style="fill:#ff0000"
     id="path107436"
     cx="4.9994659"
     cy="4.9939418"
     rx="3.4968641"
     ry="3.5023882" />
  <rect
     style="fill:#ffffff"
     id="rect108750"
     width="0.79549509"
     height="2.9389126"
     x="4.6072426"
     y="2.4638252"
     ry="0.39774755" />
  <rect
     style="fill:#ffffff"
     id="rect108752"
     width="0.79549503"
     height="2.2649515"
     x="-0.51424509"
     y="6.78125"
     ry="0.39774755"
     transform="rotate(-45)" />
</svg>
```

Нарисовал свою первую иконку. Вопрос лишь в том, как поправить данный изгиб, чтобы он не выступал за границы линий.

Допустим оконтурить в сумме две фигуры, ок, но вот поправить так, чтобы изгиб не выступал и был плавным. То есть с аналогичным радиусом, не выходит. Он либо кривой, кривой радиус, либо выступает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Изменил цвета стрелок на контрастные, чтобы лучше было видно границы
  фигур

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- После сдвига черной фигуры излом границы устранён:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраненный код после Inkscape

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="100px"
   viewBox="0 0 10 10"
   inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)"
   sodipodi:docname="Icon-ink2.svg"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg109101">
  <metadata
     id="metadata20">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="90.509668"
     inkscape:cx="49.142385"
     inkscape:cy="4.8218767"
     inkscape:window-width="1400"
     inkscape:window-height="987"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     showguides="true"
     inkscape:guide-bbox="true"
     lock-margins="true"
     inkscape:lockguides="true"
     width="10px"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg109101">
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="8.4561891,21.956885"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide104385" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="3.3824757,9.9401947"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide104395" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="1.6683301,5.0060584"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide107240" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="4.9939416,8.5415923"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide107242" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="4.0548154,8.5084466"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide107293" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="1.5026019,7.2378641"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide107295" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="5.4800775,1.5036701"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide107297" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="8.4963299,4.7519419"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide107388" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="4.6072426,6.0225244"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide107555" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="5.4027377,6.177204"
       orientation="1,0"
       id="guide107557" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="4.9939416,5.4038059"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide107559" />
    <sodipodi:guide
       position="5.4027377,4.5972623"
       orientation="0,-1"
       id="guide107561" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <defs
     id="defs109096" />
  <ellipse
     style="fill:#d81919;stroke:#e91d1d;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1"
     id="path107436"
     cx="4.9994659"
     cy="4.9939418"
     rx="3.4968641"
     ry="3.5023882" />
  <rect
     style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="rect108750"
     width="0.79549509"
     height="2.9389126"
     x="4.5961943"
     y="2.6074562"
     ry="0.39774755" />
  <rect
     style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
     id="rect108752"
     width="0.79549503"
     height="2.2649515"
     x="-0.51424509"
     y="6.78125"
     ry="0.39774755"
     transform="rotate(-45)" />
</svg>
```

Код после оптимизации [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" version="1.1" id="svg109101">
  <circle id="path107436" cx="5" cy="5" fill="#d81919" stroke="#e91d1d" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" r="3.5"/>
  <rect id="rect108750" width=".8" height="2.9" x="4.6" y="2.6" ry=".4" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width=".5" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-opacity="1"/>
  <rect id="rect108752" width=".8" height="2.3" x="-.5" y="6.8" ry=".4" transform="rotate(-45)" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width=".5" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-dasharray="none"/>
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

Для уменьшения ширины стрелок сделаем `stroke-width="0.15"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" version="1.1" id="svg109101">
  <circle id="path107436" cx="5" cy="5" fill="#d81919" stroke="#e91d1d" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" r="3.5"/>
  <rect id="rect108750" width=".8" height="2.9" x="4.6" y="2.6" ry=".4" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width=".15" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-opacity="1"/>
  <rect id="rect108752" width=".8" height="2.3" x="-.5" y="6.8" ry=".4" transform="rotate(-45)" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width=".15" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-dasharray="none"/>
</svg>
```